# Can not make class with default_random_engine field in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, random

I try to create a class that has default_random_engine private field. However, this class doesn't compile. My simple console program code follows:

```
// RngTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
private:
    default_random_engine Rng;
public:
    MyClass(void)
        : Rng(time(NULL))
    {
    }
    ~MyClass(void)
    {
    }
    void Seed(unsigned int seed)
    {
        Rng.seed(seed);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyClass rng;
    rng.Seed(100);
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio 2010 (static standard library, no MFC/ATL, console project) I see following compile error:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\random(1604): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
>   1>
>   c:\users\vitaliy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\rngtest\rngtest\rngtest.cpp(25) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::tr1::mersenne_twister<_Ty,_Wx,_Nx,_Mx,_Rx,_Px,_Ux,_Sx,_Bx,_Tx,_Cx,_Lx>::seed(_Gen &,bool)' being compiled

What may be the reason of such compilation failure? Are there any way to use default_random_engine private field in Visual C++ 2010?

Comment: The problem is that VS2010 has an incomplete implementation of C++11.

Comment: Yes, you right, I see they don't implement seeding from integer, however, they implement seeding from seed_seq, so it is required to seed with seed_seq argument and not unsigned int.

Answer (score 2):

I just spent about 4 hours trying to figure this out.  In case anyone else comes across this...

default_random_generator will *only* take a seed of type unsigned long.  Int, unsigned int, long short byte dword won't cut it.  Its got to be unsigned int.

Also note that you can't seed by 0, you'll get a runtime error.  The following is my hard-won compiling code...

```
unsigned long seed = pblock->GetInt(p_seed);
// We cannot seed with 0, so increment by 1 to avoid the error
seed++;
std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks for saving me 4 hours :)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. In Visual C++10 you have to use unsigned type for a seed!